# When is $\mathbf{X}^{T}\mathbf{X}+\lambda\mathbf{I}$ invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, statistics, regression

The question is quite simple: for a $N \times p$ matrix $\mathbf{X}$ with real entries, when is $\mathbf{X}^{T}\mathbf{X}+\lambda\mathbf{I}$ invertible (where $\mathbf{I}$ is the $p \times p$ identity matrix and $\lambda > 0$)?

This comes up in ridge regression. In *Elements of Statistical Learning* (Hastie et al.),

> [The equation] adds a positive constant to the diagonal of $\mathbf{X}^{T}\mathbf{X}$ before inversion. This makes the problem nonsingular, even if $\mathbf{X}^{T}\mathbf{X}$ is not of full rank.

I know that $\mathbf{X}^{T}\mathbf{X}$ is invertible if and only if it is of full rank if and only if $\mathbf{X}$ is of full column rank. The explanation is quite intuitive, but how do I prove it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

*$X^TX+\lambda I$ is always invertible, if $\lambda>0$.*

**Proof.** Note that, if $u\in\mathbb R^p\setminus\{0\}$, then
$$
\langle(X^TX+\lambda I)u,u\rangle
=\lambda\langle u,u\rangle+\langle X^T Xu,u\rangle
= \lambda\langle u,u\rangle+\langle Xu,Xu\rangle
\ge \lambda\langle u,u\rangle>0.
$$
Hence, $(X^TX+\lambda I)u\ne 0$, for all $u\in\mathbb R^p\setminus\{0\}$, and thus it is invertible.

**Note.** By $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ we denote the inner product in $\mathbb R^p$, and we have used the fact that
$$
\langle Ax,y\rangle=\langle x,A^Ty\rangle,\quad\text{for all $x,y\in\mathbb R^p$}.
$$ 
Also, note that $X^TX+\lambda I$ is invertible, for $\lambda>0$, even when $X$ is not a square matrix!

Comment: when A is symmetric and B is symmeric, are the eigenvalues of A+B matrix equal to the sum of eigenvalues of A and B, per each diagonal cell?