# If $X$ is not full rank, are $X^TX$ or $X^TX + \lambda I_p$ invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Suppose $X$ is a $n \times p$ matrix, where $rank(X) < p$. Since $X$ is not full rank, then it is not invertible.

I'm trying to understand whether functions of $X$ are invertible:

1. $X^TX$
2. $X^TX + \lambda I_p$ ($\lambda > 0$ is some scalar, and $I_p$ is a $p \times p$ identity matrix)
3. $X(X^TX + \lambda I_p)^{-1}X^T$

My intuition is that 1) is NOT invertible, but 2) IS invertible. Given that 2) is invertible, however, 3) is NOT invertible.

Is this correct? Can anyone help me understand why this is?

Comment: Do we have n < p or sth like that?

Comment: Hm, I've not thought about that..would the answers be different for $n < p$ vs. $n \geq p$?

Comment: To be sure to have 2) invertible, you need $\lambda$ to be strictly positive

Comment: In my understanding, answer is not different if n is greater or lower than p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\rank}{rank}$

$1$ is not invertible, and it is because $\rank X = \rank X^TX$. See [Prove that $\text{rank}(X^TX)=\text{rank}(X)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2807892/prove-that-textrankxtx-textrankx).

$2$ is invertible, as long as $\lambda > 0$. See [When is $\mathbf{X}^{T}\mathbf{X}+\lambda\mathbf{I}$ invertible?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1647625/when-is-mathbfxt-mathbfx-lambda-mathbfi-invertible).

$3$ is known as the hat matrix for ridge regression. Thanks to Brian Borchers. If $n > p$,

$$\rank X(X^TX + \lambda I)^{-1}X^T \leq \min (\rank X, \rank (X^TX + \lambda I)^{-1}X^T)$$

We know that $\rank X  <p$ and $(X^TX + \lambda I)^{-1}X^T$ is a $p \times n$ matrix. Thus $\rank (X^TX + \lambda I)^{-1}X^T \leq \min(n, p)  = p$ and it must be the case that

$$\rank X(X^TX + \lambda I)^{-1}X^T\leq \min (\rank X, \rank (X^TX + \lambda I)^{-1}X^T) < p < n$$

hence $X(X^TX + \lambda I)^{-1}X^T$ (an $n \times n$ matrix) is not invertible.

Comment: assuming that $n > p$, then $X(X^{T}X+\lambda I)^{-1}X^{T}$ has size $n$ by $n$ but its rank is $<=p$, so it's rank deficient.  Use the fact that $\mbox{rank}(AB)\leq \min(\mbox{rank}(A),\mbox{rank}(B))$

Comment: In 3), you are multiplying a full rank matrix with matrices which are not full rank. So the result cannot be full rank

Comment: @BrianBorchers Thank you so much!

Comment: It's also interesting to investigate the case where $n$ is less than the rank of $X$.

Comment: @BrianBorchers n < rk(X) is impossible no?

Comment: Sorry- I meant $n \leq p$.